# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am running a Java Spring application without using Spring Boot and I receive the following error.

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'studentService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'studentRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'studentsystem2.ikubinfo.repository.StudentRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
```

This is my **rest-servlet.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="studentsystem2.ikubinfo" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
  </beans>
```

This is my **web.xml** file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>studentsystem2</display-name>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**EDIT**
StudentRepository.java

```java
package studentsystem2.ikubinfo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import studentsystem2.ikubinfo.entity.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

I think the base package is not being found for scanning the components but I do not understand why. What's wrong with the configurations ?

Comment: I have seen the other questions but they do not answer my question.

Comment: can you please post the code of  **studentsystem2.ikubinfo.repository.StudentRepository**

Comment: @ShaileshChandra just posted

Comment: have you created JPA configuration file, persistence.xml

Comment: @ShaileshChandra no. I have only added some configuration properties in application.properties. Btw thank you for helping me :)

Comment: you need to configure your JPA, visit this URL  https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa  section **3. The JPA Spring Configuration with Java – in a non-Boot Project**

Comment: can you also try with this schema location **http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd**